# Mysql - How to set skip_networking to off?

Tags: python, mysql, database, networking, mysql-python

I'm Trying to connect to Mysql server from python. 
and i'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./db_connection.py", line 2, in <module>
    Con = MySQLdb.Connect(host="127.0.0.1",port= 3360, user="username", 
passwd="password", db="entries")
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 
85, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", 
line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL 
server on '127.0.0.1' (111)")
```

I checked and my port is 0 :

```
mysql> show variables like 'port';

+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| port          | 0     |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

and skip_networking=ON:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'skip_networking';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| skip_networking | ON    |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

file my.cnf looks like that:

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

I tried to put skip-networking = Off and port=3360 and then restart mysql service and it didn't work- skip_networking is still on.
Any suggestions on how to connect MySQL DB with python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the server is started with the `--skip-grant-tables` option to disable authentication checks, the server enables `--skip-networking` to prevent remote connections.

Yo should comment the `--skip-grant-tables`.

Comment: where should I have to comment out?

Answer (score 1):

First Thing you need to do is stop your MYSQL server.

if you are using Mac,

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

#### Then you have to put this line. the value should set to 0.

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip_networking=0
```

then you can close the terminal window, and re-open it and connect to the  mysql again. your port will be reset and, skip_networking should be reset to OFF.